# VBA to gradient fill a bubble plot and change the 'gradient' to 0

Tags: vba, excel

So essentially this is a work around - for some unknown reason, when creating a bubble map in excel you can't use 'solid fill' on negative bubbles (????!?!?). As such, the work around is to use gradient fill, then change the sliders on the 'Gradient stops' to 0 - essentially meaning there is now no gradient.

The VBA I have currently allows me to change any positive bubble to color of my choosing using 'Solid fill', however, what I need to do is have it select gradient fill, put both the gradient stop sliders to the far right hand side and choose blue for positive values and red for negative values.

Appreciate any help - this is the VBA I have currently:

```
Sub ColorPoints()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim iColor As Integer
    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("D4:D37")
    For i = 1 To myRange.Rows.Count
        Select Case WorksheetFunction.Index(myRange, i).Value
        Case -500 To 0
            iColor = 4 ' green
        Case Is > 0.0001
            iColor = 46 ' orange
        End Select
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1). _
        Points(i).Interior.ColorIndex = iColor
    Next
End Sub
```

Below is the code that the macro-recorder spit out when I recorded my desired results when doing them manually. I am having trouble understanding how to incorporate this code into my existing code.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate 
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select 
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(11).Select 
With Selection.Format.Fill 
    .Visible = msoTrue 
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1 
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0.3399999738 
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0 
    .BackColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1 
    .BackColor.TintAndShade = 0.7649999857 
    .BackColor.Brightness = 0 
    .TwoColorGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 1 
End With 
Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
```

Comment: have you tried doing this when the `macro recorder` is turned on and seeing the resulting code. this is probably the fastest (and most self-sufficient way) to solve your issue.

Comment: Yeah, I did try that. Unfortunately I can't make out which part needs to be changed in my current code to account for all these changes - each time I do try the code freezes.

Comment: What version of Excel?  I am not seeing this problem in 2013.

Comment: can you post the code that the macro-recorder made (or at least the relevant parts to changing the gradients on the bubble charts)

Comment: Thanks Scott, I was struggling with that massively!